# Laboratory Flask geometrical shape.

Tags: geometry, area, chemistry

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laboratory_flask

How one can classify Geometrical shape of Laboratory flasks especially applied in Chemistry?

Is it a Cylinder, Spherical, Oval, Cone shape?

How one can compute the area, perimeter,volume of Laboratory flask geometrical shape?

Comment: I dont't know if there is an established way of doing this, but I think you could describe the "typical" labratory flask as a conical frustum with a sylindrical neck. To compute the area, volum, etc. of this, you would simply use the formulas for a conical frustum and a sylinder and add them together.

Comment: Thanks Fenris. Combination of Cone + Cylinder geometrical shapes?

Comment: What is the type of laboratory flask you want to calculate the surface area and volume, Erlenmeyer or Florence or Dewar flask?

Comment: @Fenris little remark: $\color{red}{c}$ylindrical.